# Error in opening Silverlight 4 application thorugh aspx page in XP

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-xp

I created a silverlight business application on VS2010 in my Win7 virtual PC.
I only added a button to home.xaml..rest everything else is untouched in the template's code.

I deployed the application on IIS 7 and when I try access it on win XP machine..I get an error "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application" code: 2105

After a bit of googling I found that accessing the application through html page instead of aspx works well..and It did.

however we need windows authentication in our silverlight application, so I need aspx to work well!

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to either deploy the App on win XP or access the app from html file instead of aspx..
As for windows authentication scrip-let in aspx page,

```
<param name="Initparams" value="UserAccount=<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>" />
```

I just copied the above to html and configure IIS 7 to execute aspx code in html (handler mappings)